# How to reference "letters of gratitude" on the CV?

Tags: cv, awards

On my CV, I would like to reference some "letters of gratitude" I have received from different institutions about training courses I have given to them.

I imagine these letters could go under "Honors and Awards" section on my CV, is that right?

How should I mention these letters? Something like:

```
Letter of gratitute from [institution] on the [course details]
```

or is there any better, formal way of saying it?

Comment: What's a letter of gratitude?  In the academic systems I'm familiar with (math in the U.S.), there's no special concept of such a letter.  If you give a series of lectures, it would be polite for the organizer to write a thank you letter, but the letter carries no extra significance and wouldn't be mentioned on your CV.  (Instead, you'd just list the lecture series.)  If you are working in a context in which formal letters of gratitude carry extra weight, it would be useful to clarify in the question, as well as on your CV if you end up applying for jobs outside this context.

Comment: Thanks @ Anonymous Mathematician. Well, the thing is that I am working on two separate areas (academia and industry); in the second one, it is sometimes useful to acknowledge these thank you letters when applying for jobs. These letters come usually from official institutions who acknowledge partipation on training courses, projects, etc.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: I suggest making your comment an answer. And to add my input: the suggestion Javier posts for mentioning the letter on his CV sounds like the right way to me.

Answer (score 2):

> I am working on two separate areas (academia and industry); in the second one, it is sometimes useful to acknowledge these thank you letters when applying for jobs.

I'd recommend having two versions of your CV/resume, for use in applying to different sorts of jobs.  The industrial version could take whatever approach is standard for such applications.  For the academic version, it would be safer not to list these letters of gratitude under "Honors and Awards", since that's usually reserved for more clear-cut cases (such as prizes, awards, competitive fellowships, etc.), so including them there could look odd or like you are padding your CV.  If you'd like to mention them on the academic version of your CV as well, one possibility would be to write "received letter of gratitude from university" in parentheses after your description of the training course.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have given training to corporations or universities, this should probably be listed as a "teaching" activity on your CV. You can list general details of the kinds of courses you have given, and the frequency and kinds of institutions to which you have offered them. Referencing specific letters probably doesn't need to be done on an academic CV.